# PHP Свой механизм сессий получает неверный ID

Tags: php

**[session_set_save_handler | PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)**

```
session_set_save_handler(new MySessionHandler(), true);
session_start();
```

В методы `open` и `read`передаются id сессии. Первый вызывается `open($save_path, $session_id)`. Вот он, в качестве id почему то получает имя пользователя php, то есть '*u9534562*'. Из-за этого не получается даже завести запись сессии. А вот `read` и прочие, получают правильный аргумент, например какой-нибудь *9c4a51250dfbc6053c56ed895a727341*

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно вы неправильно понимаете для чего используется этот метод!
Смотрите справку по вашей собственной ссылке: open(string $savePath, string **$sessionName**) то есть имя, а не идентификатор. Посмотрите примеры по тексту, как это значение используется (или не используется).

Comment: Хм, хорошо, был не внимателен. Однако, при имплементации от `SessionHandlerInterface` у меня в ide автоматически генерируется метод с **$session_id**. Да и в этой [статье](http://www.sitepoint.com/writing-custom-session-handlers/) речь идет о другом. Теперь буду иметь ввиду.